# Raid 1(Mirroring) in Dell Poweredge 2850

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I need to setup a Raid 1 in Dell Poweredge 2850 Server. It has 2 scsi 73 gb disks, i am trying with Dell Server asisstant but i can't see no disk utilities. any idea ?

Comment: Do you have Open Manage installed on the server?

Answer (score 2):

Does the server have a RAID controller (PERC)? If not, you won't be able to configure RAID at the hardware level, you'll have to configure RAID at the software level in the Windows disk management mmc.

Comment: I believe the 2850 also uses a "key" to enable the PERC as well.  If that key isn't present, the RAID card is useless/invisible.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to start your server and just enter the "BIOS" utility of the RAID Controller with Ctrl-M. You'll be able to create, delete, rebuild RAID arrays.

Comment: doesn't enter   with ctrl +m. tryed because i read it in some forums.

Comment: I am not sure if that is exactly right, but it is close.  After the initial press F10 for setup, there is probably going to be a couple of (Press something for SCSI select) (Press something else for raid) utility or something like that.  And that will take you into the raid bios.  Dell support should walk you through it if you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You must activate the PERC card before configuring RAID.
Check these 3 things are they present in the server.
1. Raid controller memory.
2. Raid Battery.
3. Raid key (located in the blue socket near RAM)